# Android Bluetooth cannot connect to Medical Devices with fixed port# - use Java reflection?

Tags: android, reflection, bluetooth

I'm trying to develop an Android application for a medical device using Bluetooth SPP. My Android application works as Bluetooth server. The problem is that the medical device (UA-767PBT) may not conform SDP process and uses a fixed port# for the connection. So the connection only works after reboot the Android device.

I'm seeking the way to create a Bluetooth server side socket with a specific rfcomm channel/port# using Java reflection.

I've found some code doing the similar things using Java reflection:

1. Create Bluetooth client side socket with a specific port#.

   ```
   //Instead of using createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord 
   Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});

   // using port#1 / channel #1
   clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(mmDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
   ```
2. Inspect the port# used in Bluetooth server side socket.

   ```
   BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;
   BluetoothSocket socket;
   int port;

   serverSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(SERVICE_NAME, DEVICE_UUID);

   Field mSocketField = BluetoothServerSocket.class.getDeclaredField("mSocket");
   mSocketField.setAccessible(true);
   socket = (BluetoothSocket) mSocketField.get(serverSocket);
   mSocketField.setAccessible(false);

   Field mPortField = BluetoothSocket.class.getDeclaredField("mPort");
   mPortField.setAccessible(true);
   port = (Integer) mPortField.get(socket); 
   mPortField.setAccessible(false);

   Log.d("BT Server:", "The random port#: " + port);

   socket = serverSocket.accept();
   ```

Create Bluetooth server side socket with a specific port number. How?

I also seek other solutions for this connection problem.

Comment: Please let me know if you found any solution to this as the same problem i am facing while connecting the A&D BP and Weight scale devices.